# Laravel 4 - Method[ ] does not exist

Tags: laravel, methods, controller, routes

I'm still a novice to Laravel 4 and trying to figure out why I'm getting an error saying that Method [inventoryNotFound] does not exist. It has to do when I am attempting to use the `InventoryController@show` function.

On my Index page I have a href that I'm trying to send to the show views. The code looks like this:

```
@foreach($inventory as $item)
    <div class="col-md-4 inventory">
        <a href="{{{action('InventoryController@show')}}}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{{$item->image}}}"></a>
        <a class="description" href="">{{{$item->title}}}</a>
        @foreach($item->size_details as $details)
            <p>{{ $details->size }}: {{ $details->price }}</p>
        @endforeach

    </div>
 @endforeach
```

My show function is:

```
class InventoryController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        $inventory = Inventory::all();
        return View::make('inventories.index')->with('inventory',   $inventory);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $inventory = Inventory::find($id);

        if(is_null($inventory)){
            return $this->inventoryNotFound();
        } 

        return View::make('inventories.show',['inventory' => $inventory]);
    }

}
```

And I have a resource controller as my routes:

```
Route::resource('inventories', 'InventoryController');
```

Even when I attempt to run my routes manually, I run into the same problem.
 Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Where is your method inventoryNotFound

Comment: @Allan Pereira     public function inventoryNotFound()
 {
  return App::abort(404);
 }   It seems I forgot to add that in my controller. Now I'm getting a NotFoundHTTP exception

Comment: I have a feeling there is a syntax error in that function but you are on the right track now.

Comment: @chasenyc I believe you're right. Thanks so much for the help!